# How to enable TLSv1.1+ with httpClient 4.1.2 in Android (API 16 - 19)

Tags: java, android, ssl, tls1.2

My Question is simple as in subject line:

How to enable TLSv1.1+ with httpClient 4.1.2 in Android (API 16 - 19)

I have referred multiple post and blogs online.
The closest one was : http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/

But this is not for httpClient.

Please guide me. If I need to use some custom SSLSocketFactory, then let me know how to integrate it to my DefaultHttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it with some help. Posting it so that it will help someone.

I used this link https://github.com/erickok/transdroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/transdroid/daemon/util/TlsSniSocketFactory.java

Once you include that file in your code, just refer them as in below code.

```
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("https", new TlsSniSocketFactory(), 443));
client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry),httpParameters);
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: it says Scheme() in Scheme cannot be applied to: